# Why is Windows Vista 64-bit using a 32-bit cmd.exe by default? (machine-specific)

Tags: windows-vista, 32bit-64bit, cmd, system32, syswow64

**The situation:**

I need to convert our current development environment from Windows XP 32-bit to Windows Vista 64-bit (*). Naturally, I've run into plenty of places in our build system where hardcoded paths were problematic (e.g. "`C:\Program Files`" becoming "`C:\Program Files (x86)`"). Fortunately, there is a `%ProgramFiles%` environment variable which maps to the proper directory based on the source process (32-bit or 64-bit). So I updated the build scripts with `%ProgramFiles%`, and I was sure it'd be the end of that.

The build environment is called from the command-line (`C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`).

**The problem:**
On one specific machine (namely my dev machine at work), it turns out that `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` is actually a 32bit process, so the scripts find the `x86` version of the `Program Files` directory and everything works great.

On every other 64bit machine I can find (including my home machine), `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` is the 64bit version, and the 32bit version is in `C:\Windows\SysWow64\cmd.exe`. So the build scripts can't find anything they're looking for and fail.

I understand now that the 32bit `cmd.exe` should be called explicitly if that's what you need, and by default you get a 64bit `cmd.exe`. Typical case of `WORKSFORME`...

**The question is**, what happened to the machine where this is not true? Why am I getting a 32bit `cmd.exe` by default on one machine but not on others? In all cases I am explicitly executing `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` from the `Start|Run` menu but getting different results *on one machine only*. All are running the same edition of Vista 64bit.

Any thoughts or insight?

(*) Please accept that I *must* do this. I am not at liberty to say *why* I am doing this. Re-installing the OS and everything from scratch would probably work, but it is surely overkill. Besides, it was hard enough convincing our IT department to give out Vista machines!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally found the problem, and as expected it is quite simple: user error. Explorer (which is itself a 64-bit process on Windows Vista 64-bit) launches 64-bit command prompts by default. If you want a 32-bit `CMD.EXE`, you must explicitly reference `C:\Windows\SysWoW64\CMD.EXE`.

The reason this worked fine on my system is that I use Far Manager for most of my command-line usage, which is 32-bit (therefore it launches 32-bit command prompts). When I verified I must have confused a 32-bit window for a 64-bit window (after all they look the same!) and asked a stupid question.

Die in Sente, the problem with `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` is that it doesn't exist on Windows Vista 32-bit, because that would have really been simpler.

Ah, there is nothing like a public posting to make a fool of yourself... :)

Answer (score 2):

If you ran cmd from a 32-bit process, you'd get the 32-bit cmd because of File Redirection (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187.aspx). Do you get the 32-bit version of CMD when you run it from Explorer?

Answer (score 1):

`cmd.exe` is launched from within the Start menu on both machines. Exact repro:

- Click the Start Orb
- Type "`cmd`", only one match comes up (`c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe`)
- Launch it.

On my work machine, it launches the 32bit version (as demonstrated by the Task Manager, it has `*32` appended to the name in the `Processes` tab). On all other Vista 64 machines I've tried, this launches the 64bit version of `cmd`, and I cannot find a rational explanation for this behavior.

I haven't checked if `explorer.exe` itself was 32bit or 64bit on the affected machine, maybe this is related... Thanks for the hint.

Comment: After verification, the explorer.exe process is 64bit on all machines. I don't understand how a 64bit process defaults to launching the 32bit version of cmd... :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `%ProgramFiles%`, isn't there a `%Programfiles(x86)%` that always goes where you want, regardless of which cmd.exe is running? My Windows XP 64-bit systems all have that; excuse me for not taking the time to boot up a Vista system.